# ANDROID: Request Code for Permissions not appearing

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm sure this has a very simple explanation, but it has me stumped. With the new updates to API 23, you must declare permissions both in the manifest and in the actual code. Yet the request code for what I am trying to do does not appear.

Here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ryanfolz.textscrabble">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And in my first activity I call this method:

```
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS")
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
    }
```

However, the "REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS" doesn't link to any numeric value. In fact, there are no request codes the appear in the autocomplete either.

Does anyone know why this code does not appear and how to fix it?

Comment: Well, you need to define `REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS` yourself. That's your code, to distinguish one permission request from any others that you may be making in this activity.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign an arbitrary value to `REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS`. you should declare `REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS` as a constant with an arbitrary numerical value like

`public final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1001;`

this value is used to know which permissions are allowed and manage in `onRequestPermissionsResult`. i.e, you asks permissions on two different situations in same activity, and you have only one `onRequestPermissionsResult` method. So you have to distinguish which result is catched in `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

So if you have two requests, say for SMS, and for WAKE_LOCK, you are requesting with two request codes, say:

```
public final int REQUEST_CODE_SMS_PERMISSIONS = 1001;
public final int REQUEST_CODE_WAKELOCK_PERMISSIONS = 1002;
```

So that you can manage the result in `onRequestPermissionsResult` like this

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode){
             case REQUEST_CODE_SMS_PERMISSIONS:
                 //Code for handling SMS Permission results
                 break;
             case REQUEST_CODE_WAKELOCK_PERMISSIONS:
                 //Code for handling WAKE_LOCK Permission results
                 break;
          }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and when I had to request permission I simply defined and Integer called REQUEST_CODE. Like:

```
final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

Then I called:

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE);

Then onRequestPermission call, I handle if request code equals my REQUEST_CODE integer.

So just define an integer to call for a permission.

May not be the exact sollution you are looking for, but it works.